# Catching errors and warnings in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

PHP code designed to catch an error caused by a query that takes too long to execute (in this case one second, by design).

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

$conn->query('SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000'); 

try{
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)['COUNT(1)'];
}

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "query probably took too long: ". $e;
}
```

The following warnings are displayed on the browser:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/3024): Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded 

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool
```

Why am I still getting hit with these warnings on the browser? Surely, if I am catching these errors then I don't need warnings. I understand that warnings can be supressed, but is it possible to amend the code to prevent the warnings?

Edit: $sql is must the query, `"SELECT Count(1) FROM table WHERE..."`

Comment: What is query $sql

Comment: $sql is a text string like "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM... " I will edit and mention that it is the query for clarity.

Comment: Can you check your connection is working or not.

Comment: Connection to the database is not the issue, its the timeout of the query execution as per the error warnings.

Comment: I edited the other answer you got earlier, so now you can use the code from there.